# Creating a custom LinearLayout from within a custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm designing my own tab control.  I've created 2 custom views.  The first is called `MyTab` and derives from `LinearLayout`.  The second is called `MyTabBar` and derives from `LinearLayout`.

The constructor of both look something like this:

```
public MyTab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_my_tab, this);
}
```

`MyTabBar` has a member variable which is an `ArrayList` of `MyTab`s.  I have a public function called `addTab(String strTabName)` to add a new `MyTab` to the `MyTabBar`.  My question is, when I do the following:

```
MyTab tab = new MyTab(...);
```

inside of `MyTabBar`, how do I obtain the `Context` and `AttributeSet` required to be passed to `MyTab`?

Or should I be inflating it somehow?

Comment: you shouldn't inflate in a view's constructor, i don't think this is what you want to do

Comment: the inflater.inflate method returns a view that you are not using, you are not storing it and you can't return it in a constructor, you are confusing inflation and construction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view's constructor with a AttributeSet parameter is used only when you inflate the view from an xml file, otherwise write a constructor having only a Context parameter, and use super(context);
to get the context from MyTabBar, use this.getContext();